# Linear algebra estimates

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis

Here is something that has been troubleing me lately. I don't know if it is true of not. I suspect it is.

Suppose that $A,B$ are two $n \times n$ matrices with complex entries. $A^t = A$, $\bar B^t = B$, and B is positive i.e. $\bar \xi ^t B \xi > 0$ for any $\xi \in \Bbb C^n$. If $$|\xi ^t A \xi| \leq |\xi|^2 + \bar \xi^t B \xi \ for \ any \ \xi \in \Bbb C^n.$$

Is it true that there exists a symmetric matrix $C$ with complex entries such that 
$$|\xi ^t C \xi| \leq |\xi|^2$$
$$|\xi ^t (A-C) \xi| \leq \bar \xi^t B \xi \ for \ any \ \xi \in \Bbb C^n.$$

In the case $n=1$, this is obviously true, but in higher dimensions this does not seem obvious.

Comment: It stems from a somewhat technical problem that I am thinking about in differential geometry. As it looks I am sure that was not obvious, but I tried to dumb the question down to a level that is not technical enough but still relevant. The problem in question will not solve anything major, but it seems to have some interest of its own ---> Any symmetric complex bilinear form dominated by the sum of two different norms can be decomposed into a sum of two symmetric bilinear forms dominated by each of the norms separately and there is no increase of norms involved in this process.